# C# error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my player to give a speed boost for a few seconds. When it collects 4 items (paintCount = 4), the player gets a movement speed boost for a short period of time.
I always have an error in the class Paintser: `SimplePlayer0.SpeedUp();`.
I've tried many things to counter it, but none of them are working.
I'm working in Unity.

Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SimplePlayer0.SpeedUp().

This is the players script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SimplePlayer0 : MonoBehaviour
{

  // SPEEDVARIABLES
  public static float speed = 3.5f;


  // BONUSSPEED
  private static float speedBoostTime;
  public static float SpeedBoostTime
  {
    get
    {
      return speedBoostTime;
    }
    set
    {
      speedBoostTime = value;
    }
  }



   // BONUSSPEED
   public void SpeedUp()
  {
    speed *= 2;
    SpeedBoostTime = 3; // seconds
  }

   void Update()
   {
    // BONUSSPEED
    while (speedBoostTime > 0)
    {
     speedBoostTime -= Time.deltaTime;
     if (speedBoostTime <= 0) speed /= 2;
    }
  }
```

This is the power up script, where the gameobject gets destroyed.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
  {
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
      Paintser.ExtraTime();
      Destroy(this.gameObject);
      Paintser.paintCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

And finally the script where all the magic  (or errors) happens:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Paintser : PowerUp
{

  public static int paintCount = 0;
  public int speedBoostTime = 3;

  public static void ExtraTime()
  {
    if (paintCount == 4)
    {

      SimplePlayer0.SpeedUp();

      Paintser.paintCount = Paintser.paintCount = 0;

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SpeedUp` method is an *instance member* of `SimplePlayer0` class.

Thus, you need to call it as an instance method:

```
SimplePlayer0 player0 = new SimplePlayer0();
player0.SpeedUp();
```

Comment: The error is gone, thank you. Unfortunately my player isn't going faster suddently.

Comment: @ToondeJonge I see... Well, actually I'm not an Unity developer but I found I could assist you on this generic issue :D

Comment: It's a struggle I got to face. I'll find the answer in the end ^^

Comment: @ToondeJong Responding to your speed boost not applying, verify that your code in the method 'SpeedUp();' is being called correctly. Its looks like it is but what I don't see is how that speed boost is being applied to that characters movement in any way. You need to Apply this to his Character Controller or Transform in some way.

Comment: I didn't upload the part for the players movement. It is in the SimplePlayer0 class tho. I just need te reffer to the player speed, right? The bonus speed worked at the beginning, but when I want to control it with a time limit it doesn't work.