# Unity C#: Error when trying to call a class' functions in Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following (relevant) code:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

public class Timer
{
    int elapsedTime;
    int pausedTime;

    bool isCounting;
    public void Start()
    {
        int startTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        while(isCounting)
        {
            elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond - startTime;
        }
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    //Debug logging of the timer functions
    if(startButton.CompareTag("Clicked"))
    {
        Timer.Start();
    }

}
```

}

This code generates the following error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'GameController.Timer.Start()`. How can I fix this?

(Note: The cause of this error is different for almost every scenario so it's pretty hard to call it a duplicate.)

Comment: You cannot use a class object without instantiating it. As you have declared your own Timer Class. Create a object out of it and  use it. So Rule of thumb is any non static class which you wan to use instantiate it object first. Read this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792986/c-sharp-error-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Update()` you're calling `Timer.Start();`. This is a call to a static method of the class `Timer`. This static method does not exist and therefore you get the error. Making the method static is no option, since it uses the non static member `elapsedTime`. The fix to the problem will then be to have an instance of a Timer and call the method on this:

```
public class Timer
{
    int elapsedTime;
    int pausedTime;

    bool isCounting;

    public void Start()
    {
        int startTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

        while(isCounting)
        {
            elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond - startTime;
        }
    }
}

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // The new member
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    private void Update()
    {
        //Debug logging of the timer functions
        if(startButton.CompareTag("Clicked"))
        {
            this.timer.Start();
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Better still to instantiate `Timer` within the `Start()` lifecycle method

Comment: Got it, thank you! I didn't know I had to instantiate the class.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    public class Timer
    {
        int elapsedTime;
        int pausedTime;

        bool isCounting;
        public void Start()
        {
            int startTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

            while(isCounting)
            {
                elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond - startTime;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Debug logging of the timer functions
        if(startButton.CompareTag("Clicked"))
        {
            Timer.Start();
        }    
    }
}
```

you have two options for this problem

1. you have make method static:

   ```
   public static void Start()
   {
       int startTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

       while(isCounting)
       {
           elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond - startTime;
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can access the start Method by creating object class timer:

   ```
   Timer obj= new Timer()
   obj.Start();
   ```

Comment: Making it static won't work, as I've described in my answer. Why did you just copy his code sample without any modifications?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé it can be done with different way and according to our need too.

Comment: sure it can. But what you propose under 1 will lead to a compiler error, since elapsedTime is an instance member, that can't be accessed from a static method